# Do 301 redirects work on urls that contain query strings?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I've searched for this but the answers I've found seem to be around rewriting URLs or for redirecting lots of pages in an entire section and look confusing (lots of regex).

We need to add some 301 redirects and everything is working fine except for 13 URLs that contain query strings.

Is there a trick to redirecting these kinds of urls?

```
Redirect 301 /blogsearch/?akID%5B30%5D%5BatSelectOptionID%5D%5B%5D=39 /blogsearch/Coffee
Redirect 301 /blogsearch/?akID%5B30%5D%5BatSelectOptionID%5D%5B%5D=26 /blogsearch/Food
Redirect 301 /blogsearch/?akID%5B30%5D%5BatSelectOptionID%5D%5B%5D=27 /blogsearch/Wine
Redirect 301 /blogsearch/?akID%5B30%5D%5BatSelectOptionID%5D%5B%5D=29 /blogsearch/Travel
Redirect 301 /blogsearch/?akID%5B30%5D%5BatSelectOptionID%5D%5B%5D=37 /blogsearch/Hotel
Redirect 301 /blogsearch/?akID%5B30%5D%5BatSelectOptionID%5D%5B%5D=49 /blogsearch/Apartments
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there's a trick. You can't use `Redirect` directive with query strings.

You could just do something like this with `mod-rewrite`. Just change the corresponding query string value for every individual link you have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=39
RewriteRule ^blogsearch/?$ /blogsearch/Coffee? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=26
RewriteRule ^blogsearch/?$ /blogsearch/Food? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=27
RewriteRule ^blogsearch/?$ /blogsearch/Wine? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=29
RewriteRule ^blogsearch/?$ /blogsearch/Travel? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=37
RewriteRule ^blogsearch/?$ /blogsearch/Hotel? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)=49
RewriteRule ^blogsearch/?$ /blogsearch/Apartments? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I now understand about Rewrite! However, I've added these rules, reloaded apache but they don't seem to work. We have other rewrite rules for pretty URLS so I added them afterward these, within the same ````<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>```` - does that sound correct? Also tried them in their own if statement as well.

Comment: Did these go in your .htaccess file or in your apache config?

Comment: Also i would put these before any other rules I can't see what you have but that is a safe bet.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I put them before any other rules in the .htacces and it works. Just a quick question, does this actually fix the duplicate content issue? Because obviously the duplicate links still exist so presumably Google will still index the links before they're re-written right?

Comment: the 301 shows this is the permanent new URL so once Google reindexes it should be ok.

Comment: OK, so do I need to leave the 301 redirects in there in addition to the URL rewriting?

Comment: The ones that are working, leave, the ones you had with query strings that don't work, use my rules for those 13 links.